# Exponential integral of 2 functions

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

I have a function of time t that is defined as :

$$ M(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{f(x)(t-g(x))}dx $$

Where f and g are strictly increasing functions. My questions is for which classes/families of functions f and g is this integral solvable and what are the solutions? I know that for f and g linear there is solution:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{ax(t-bx)}dx = \dfrac{\sqrt{{\pi}}\mathrm{e}^\frac{at^2}{4b}\left(\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}t}{2\sqrt{b}}\right)+1\right)}{2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}}$$

I'm would especially be interested in geometric forms for f.

**Edit**:
If easier, solutions for the discrete sum would also be useful: $$ M(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{f(n)(t-g(n))} $$ with f geometric and g linear :
$$ M(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{ax^n(t-bn)} $$

**Context**:
I'm actually studying $F(t) = \frac{1}{M(t)}\frac{dM(t)}{dt} $ for which I have analitical solutions with the finite discrete sum. Another idea is to swith to a stochastic setting with $ M_t = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{f_n(t-g_n)} $ where $(f_n) \sim 1 + \chi^2 (2)$ (or $Exp(\lambda)$) and $(g_n) \sim  Pois(\lambda) $. Maybe a SDE for dFt may be found.

Comment: For $f=ax^k$ and $g=bx^k$ we can evaluate this in terms of confluent hypergeometric functions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with hypergeometric functions but I don't see how we could express M with power series.  And I don't think  $M(a,b,t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{a x^k (t-b x^k )}dx$ satisfies Kulmar's differential equation either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this integral could be solvable if $f$ was $f(x)=x^3$ and $g$ was $g(x)=x^5$.

Consider the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\left(x^3\right)\left(x-\left(x^5\right)\right)}dx.$$ Normally, the solution to it would be 1.21 because we have not defined a variable for $x$ to be raised by. But by replacing $x^3$ and $x^5$ with their respective functions, we get a wide variety of solutions:

| $t$ | $M(t)$ |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.94 |
| 1 | 1.26 |
| 2 | 1.94 |
| 3 | 3.69 |
| 4 | 9.09 |
| 5 | 29.05 |

**rounded to the nearest hundredth*

The table could keep going on and on forever, thus proving that there are **infinite solutions** to the integral.

---

That's all I have; Let me know if my answer helped you or not.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).